# How does a document reference an SCSS file?

Tags: css, sass

please excuse my inexperience with, and lack of understanding of, Sass.

Basically I was assigned to do some edits on a site which has a main css page and a few scss subpages, all organized through an ftp directory.

I'm just confused how the index knows where to pull the scss pages in the ftp directory? I've looked through the code for the index page, as well as the linked css and js pages, and can't find any part that references the scss pages. Yet they still load within the original css? Am I missing something?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Is there any gulpfile.js or grunt file in the main directory? In which language is the application? Ruby?

Comment: no there aren't any gulpfile.js or grunt files. the website is in javascript, html and css with scss

Comment: There is usually a 'compile' or 'pre-processing' that is done to SCSS, stylus and other css pre-processors to turn them in css files which are linked up to the index/html pages. There is a good chance the person who set this up can give you more guidance, assuming they are still around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCSS is a preprocessor language. That means it will be converted to CSS. The SCSS files do not get loaded by the website. Instead you will have to make your changes to the SCSS files and then convert them to CSS. It is likely that there is a system in place which takes care of that for you. Take a look around and find out whether there is a `gulpfile` or a `gruntfile` hanging out somewhere.

The main.scss file gets compiled to the main.css file. The output produced by the sass compiler replaces the main.css file. There is no link. You need to compile your main.scss file using sass.

Apart from that, you use 'CSS file' rather than 'CSS page' as CSS is an acronym for cascading style sheet which is definitely not page in itself.

Comment: Hi Franz, thanks for the quick response. If there are elements such as mixins in a SCSS file that are referenced by the main CSS file, how does the CSS file link to or find the SCSS file within itself if that makes sense?

Comment: SCSS uses the regular `@import` syntax: http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4 . If there is no import call, the files are probably concatenated before compilation. The first step right here is finding out which build tool is used. Someone at your workplace should know it.

Comment: You can also post a screenshot of the directory structure. Maybe I can gather something from it.

Comment: as far as I know, the index page of the site is sourcing from the main.css, but I can't for the life of me figure out how it's also referencing the setup scss files within the main.css

Comment: The inclusion is most likely happening in the main.scss file. Did you take a look there?
A grunt/ or gulpfile might be in the CSS folder's parent directory.

Comment: As @Matt stated, it might also be possible that your server or browser do the conversion. So there might actually be no build system in place.

Comment: yes, the main.scss file has all of the @imports you mentioned, but how does that ultimately link to the main.css file?

Comment: the main.scss file gets compiled to the main.css file. The output produced by the sass compiler replaces the main.css file. There is no link.
You need to compile your main.scss file using sass.
This should help: https://prepros.io/
+ No problem.

Comment: @Jema I don't know how far you have gotten with all this preprocessor stuff by now, but you can in fact compile source maps that get parsed by chrome and firefox. With the help of these sourcemaps, you are referencing the css file transparently e.g. you will see the scss source in the inspector instead of the compiled css!

Answer (score 1):

Web browsers don't know what a SCSS or SASS file is. They only load CSS.

Your site could have a build tool (`grunt`, `gulp`, `rake` etc) to compile your `.scss` source files into `.css` files, which is then published to your web site.

Sometimes your application server will know how to do the translation on the fly and you can just edit the `.scss` file.

A lot of the time many `.scss` files will be combined into one `.css` file so you are often editing a different file to what you would expect when you look at what `.css` is loaded the browser.